# Disable a selected option if is selected already getting empty value in alert

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello everyone I am using this script to check if a option is already selected then disable that option, Now I am trying to get selected values I am not getting anything in alert.

Html

```
<h4 class="info-text">Select 1st Employee<br>
   <select name="wcl-employees1" id="wcl-employees1">
    <option value="" disabled="" selected="" style="display:none;">Select One...</option>
    <option value="ALCANTARA, ERIC">ALCANTARA, ERIC</option>
    <option value="ALDRIGE, ,MERANDA">ALDRIGE, ,MERANDA</option>
    <option value="ALTOBELLI, JAMES">ALTOBELLI, JAMES</option>
</select>
```

```
<h4 class="info-text">Select 2nd Employee<br>
         <select name="wcl-employees2" id="wcl-employees2">
        <option value="" disabled="" selected="" style="display:none;">Select One...</option>
    <option value="ALCANTARA, ERIC">ALCANTARA, ERIC</option>
    <option value="ALDRIGE, ,MERANDA">ALDRIGE, ,MERANDA</option>
    <option value="ALTOBELLI, JAMES">ALTOBELLI, JAMES</option>
</select>
```

```
<h4 class="info-text">Select 3rd Employee<br>
   <select name="wcl-employees3" id="wcl-employees3">
    <option value="" disabled="" selected="" style="display:none;">Select One...</option>
    <option value="ALCANTARA, ERIC">ALCANTARA, ERIC</option>
    <option value="ALDRIGE, ,MERANDA">ALDRIGE, ,MERANDA</option>
    <option value="ALTOBELLI, JAMES">ALTOBELLI, JAMES</option>
</select>
```

```
<Script>
var $select = $("select");
$select.on("change", function() {
    var selected = [];  
    alert(selected);
    $.each($select, function(index, select) {           
        if (select.value !== "") { selected.push(select.value); }
    });         
   $("option").prop("disabled", false);         
   for (var index in selected) { $('option[value="'+selected[index]+'"]').prop("disabled", true); }
});
```

Database insertion code:

```
public function insertTeam()
{
    $team_code=$_POST['fav1'].','.$_POST['fav2'].','.$_POST['fav3'].','.$_POST['fav4'].','.$_POST['fav5'];
    $user_id  =$_POST['fav6'];
    $verified = self :: checkFavTeams( $_POST['fav6'] );

    if($verified['totalrow']>0)
    {
        $sql=$this->db->prepare("update favteam set team_code='$team_code' where user_id='$user_id'");
        $sql->execute();
        if ( $sql->rowCount() != 0 ) {
                return( 1 );
            }  else {
                  return ( 3 );
             }
    }
    else
    {
        $sql = $this->db->prepare("insert into favteam (team_code,user_id) values ('$team_code','$user_id')");
        $sql->execute();
        if ( $sql->rowCount() != 0 ) {
                    return( 1 );
                }  else {
                      return ( 3 );
                 }
    }
}
```

Comment: declare `var selected = []; ` outside `on` handler

Comment: alert after the each loop

Comment: I am getting the value but not it's not going in database....but if i am removing this script then it's going in database..

Comment: how is it sent to the database

Comment: check above i have updated my code..